# How to use a while loop to prompt user until they enter 1 of 4 inputs

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm stuck on how to get this while loop to function properly. I want the program to prompt the user with a question 'Rock, paper, or scissors?' to which they can correctly enter 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors', or 'bomb' (cheat code for auto-win... lol). If they type in anything other than those 4 acceptable inputs, an alert should appear. Then they should be prompted with the same question again. This should repeat until they enter one of those 4 acceptable inputs.

So far, it works if they type in their choice correctly the first time the prompt appears. However, if they type something other than the above 4 acceptable inputs, triggering the alert and the prompt in the while loop, the program does not run correctly even if they enter one of the 4 inputs the next time they are prompted. It gets stuck alternating between the alert and the prompt for eternity.

So how can I get this while loop to work?

```
function playGame () {
    var input = prompt ('Rock, paper, or scissors?').toLowerCase();
    // testing 123
    // console.log (input);
    var jkl = 0;
    if (input === 'rock' || input === 'paper' || input === 'scissors' || input === 'bomb') {
        jkl++
    };
    while (jkl === 0) {
        alert ('ErRoR eRrOr 3rR0r!!!!11');
        prompt ('Rock, paper, or scissors?').toLowerCase();
        if (input === 'rock' || input === 'paper' || input === 'scissors' || input === 'bomb') {
            jkl++
        };
    }
    console.log (input);
    var userChoice = getUserChoice (input);
    var computerChoice = getComputerChoice ();
    console.log (`You: ${userChoice}`);
    console.log (`Computer: ${computerChoice}`);
    console.log (determineWinner (userChoice, computerChoice));
};

playGame ();
```

After the attempted while loop there is more code that pertains to functions appearing earlier in the program. Ignore that I suppose. Unless anyone thinks it's relevant, in which case I can post that too. Just didn't want to paste a massive wall of code in here.

Comment: Typo.  When you prompt for the value within the loop you don't actually store that value in a variable.  `input` is never modified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `input` variable in the loop.

```js
const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'bomb']
const getOptionPrompt = () => prompt('Rock, paper, or scissors?').toLowerCase();
const checkOption = (input, options) => options.includes(input)

function playGame() {
  let input = getOptionPrompt();
  // testing 123
  // console.log (input);
  var jkl = 0;
  if (checkOption(input, options)) {
    jkl++
  };
  while (jkl === 0) {
    alert('ErRoR eRrOr 3rR0r!!!!11');
    input = getOptionPrompt();
    if (checkOption(input, options)) {
      jkl++
    };
  }
  console.log(input);
  // the functions after this are not defined in the example
  /*
  var userChoice = getUserChoice(input);
  var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  console.log(`You: ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`Computer: ${computerChoice}`);
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
  */
};

playGame();
```

But I would definitely update the logic a bit:

```js
const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'bomb']
const getOptionPrompt = () => prompt('Rock, paper, or scissors?')?.toLowerCase() || null;
const checkOption = (input, options) => options.includes(input)

function playGame(options) {
  const input = getOptionPrompt();

  if (!checkOption(input, options) && input != null) {
    alert('ErRoR eRrOr 3rR0r!!!!11');
    playGame(options)
  } else if (input == null) {
    console.log("game canceled")
  } else {
    console.log("result:", input)
  }
};

playGame(options);
```

This way you don't need the `jkl` variable, no need for the `while` loop - if an answer is typed in that is not acceptable, then an error alert shows & the game starts anew.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain what lines 1-3 are in your examples? I am not familiar with some of the syntax you are using. I am a couple weeks into a JavaScript fundamentals course so my understanding is limited.

Comment: @ChrisNelson those lines are the basic data and utility functions for the game. It's usually better to decompose the functions like this, so you can keep your code clean (easy to read, easy to reason about, easier to debug).

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line

```
prompt ('Rock, paper, or scissors?').toLowerCase();
```

to

```
input = prompt ('Rock, paper, or scissors?').toLowerCase();
```

Your code is checking the input variable without updating it.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I then changed the code inside of the while loop to an if...else statement and deleted the if statement above the while loop.